# ValueError: Number of Coefficients does not match number of features (Mglearn visualization)

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, valueerror

I am trying to perform a sentiment analysis based on product reviews collected from various websites. I've been able to follow along with the below article until it gets to the model coefficient visualization step.

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-a-simple-algorithm-classifies-texts-with-moderate-accuracy-79f0cd9eb47

When I run my program, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Number of coefficients 6021 doesn't match number offeature names 6290.
```

Any advice on how to ensure the number of coefficients match the number of features in my dataset?

Below is my code:

```
y = reviews['Review Type']
X = reviews['Review Comment']

#Split the data into training and test sets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
text_train, text_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

#run the feature extraction on training & test independent variables with bag of words
#changing the variable back to X_train after transforming it.

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
vect = CountVectorizer().fit(text_train)
X_train = vect.transform(text_train)
print(repr(X_train))

X_test = vect.transform(text_test)
print(repr(X_test))

feature_names = vect.get_feature_names()
print(len(feature_names))

#running a logistic regression model to predict whether a review is positive 
#or negative

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, class_weight='balanced', random_state=0)
param_grid = {'C': [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]}


grid = GridSearchCV(logreg, param_grid, scoring= 'roc_auc', cv=5)
logreg_train = grid.fit(X_train, y_train)

pred_logreg = logreg_train.predict(X_test)
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_logreg)
print(confusion)
print("Classification accuracy is: ", (confusion[0][0] + confusion[1][1]) / np.sum(confusion))

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set();

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, grid.decision_function(X_test))
# find threshold closest to zero:
close_zero = np.argmin(np.abs(thresholds))
plt.plot(fpr[close_zero], tpr[close_zero], 'o', markersize=10, 
 label= 'threshold zero(default)', fillstyle= 'none', c='k', mew=2)
plt.plot([0,1], linestyle='-', lw=2, color='r', label='random', alpha=0.8)
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.plot(fpr, tpr, label='ROC Curve')
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate (recall)')
plt.title('roc_curve');
from sklearn.metrics import auc
print('AUC score is: ', auc(fpr, tpr));


from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(\
                                                      y_test, logreg_train.decision_function(X_test))
close_zero = np.argmin(np.abs(thresholds))
plt.plot(precision[close_zero], recall[close_zero], 'o', markersize=10, 
         label="threhold zero", fillstyle="none", c="k", mew=2)
plt.plot(precision, recall, label="precision recall curve")
plt.xlabel("precision")
plt.ylabel("recall")
plt.title("Precision Recall Curve")
plt.legend(loc="best");

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
logreg = LogisticRegression(max_iter=10000, class_weight="balanced", random_state=0)
pipe = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(norm=None, stop_words='english'), logreg)
param_grid = {'logisticregression__C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]}
grid = GridSearchCV(pipe, param_grid, scoring="roc_auc", cv=5)
logreg_train = grid.fit(text_train, y_train)

fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_test, grid.decision_function(text_test))
pred_logreg = logreg_train.predict(text_test)
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, pred_logreg)
print(confusion)
print("Classification accuracy is: ", (confusion[0][0] + confusion[1][1]) / np.sum(confusion)) 
print("Test AUC score is: ", auc(fpr, tpr));

mglearn.tools.visualize_coefficients(grid.best_estimator_.named_steps["logisticregression"].coef_,feature_names, n_top_features=25)
```

Comment: *Where exactly*? Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined `feature_names` in terms of the features from a `CountVectorizer` with the default `stop_words=None`, but your model in the last bit of code is using a `TfidfVectorizer` with `stop_words='english'`.  Use instead

```py
feature_names = grid.best_estimator_.named_steps["tfidfvectorizer"].get_feature_names()
```